# Issue with displaying header and SVG element

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

When I display a header and a SVG element, on mobile devices the width of the header is some px smaller than the width of the page and the viewBox is not displayed correct. On desktop it will display the horziontal scrollbar though I set the width to 100% in CSS or use window.screen.width*window.devicePixelRatio in JavaScript. I want simple a header and a content like the Stack Overflow page. What I do wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #58CCED;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #header {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #072F5F;
      padding: 40px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <svg id="viewport" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 0 0" style="fill: red; outline: 5px solid black">
      <!-- draw objects -->
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
    </svg>
    <script>
      // document.getElementById("header").style.width = (window.screen.width*window.devicePixelRatio);

      viewport.setAttribute("width", (window.screen.width*window.devicePixelRatio)-20);
      viewport.setAttribute("height", (window.screen.height*window.devicePixelRatio));

      viewport.setAttribute("viewBox","0 0 "+((window.screen.width*window.devicePixelRatio)-20)+" "+ ((window.screen.height*window.devicePixelRatio)));
    </script>
  </body>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing several things wrong here.

1. The padding you are adding to `#header` is added to the 100% width you have set. Meaning the header is now wider than the page.  So you will get a horizontal scroll bar. 
   This is how the standard box model works.  To include padding and border width in the 100%, use `box-sizing: border-box;`.
2. The same applies to the border you are adding to the SVG. Use the same fix.
3. Finally you are using `viewBox` wrong.  `viewBox` is meant to describe the size of the SVG contents. Not the size of the viewport.  It should be set to `viewBox="0 0 100 100"` to match the size of the `<rect>`.
4. You don't need any Javascript here.

```css
body {
  background-color: #58CCED;
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #072F5F;
  padding: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#viewport {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<svg id="viewport" width="0" height="0" viewBox="0 0 100 100" style="fill: red; outline: 5px solid black">
  <!-- draw objects -->
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. The header is displaying correct now. I use the viewBox this way because I scale the viewPort so it will fit the viewBox.